# Entity Framework Core Eager Loading Then Include on a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have three Models that I want to include when performing a query.

Here is the scenario.

```cs
public class Sale
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<SaleNote> SaleNotes { get; set; }
}

public class SaleNote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can eager load the SaleNotes like this...

```
_dbContext.Sale.Include(s => s.SaleNotes);
```

However, trying to eager load the User model from the SaleNote using ThenInclude is challenging because it is a collection. I cannot find any examples on how to eager load this scenario. Can someone supply the code the goes in the following ThenInclude to load the User for each item in the collection.

```
_dbContext.Sale.Include(s => s.SaleNotes).ThenInclude(...);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It doesn't matter that `SaleNotes` is collection navigation property. It should work the same for references and collections:

```
_dbContext.Sale.Include(s => s.SaleNotes).ThenInclude(sn=>sn.User);
```

But as far I know, EF7 also supports the old multi-level Include syntax using Select extension method:

```
_dbContext.Sale.Include(s => s.SaleNotes.Select(sn=>sn.User));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually found that although User was not showing up in the intellisense, I added sn.User, built my solution, and it ran! The intellisense was treating the SaleNotes "sn" in the lambda expression as a collection, so it was not showing the individual properties of the User class.

Comment: @AllenRufolo there are two overloads, one which gives you the whole list (first one, and default one), another which gives you each item in the list (second one) - so, if you just do "down arrow" in the intellisense, you'll see the expected intellisense options. I had the same confusion myself :-)

Comment: Allen, you are absolutely correct.  I am using EF Core 2.0 on VS 2017 15.4 and the intelliesense is not working, but if you just type in the property name you need, it will be fine. This helped me out a bunch.

Comment: @AllenRufolo Thank you for your comment about not showing in intellisense. It's crazy bug! You've saved me a lot of energy! I'd never guess that intellisense might not work here.

Comment: @Landeeyo I'm surprised they haven't fixed this by now to be honest. My comment was a year and a half ago and people are still upvoting it. Glad I could help!

Comment: @AllenRufolo I hope they'll do it. I've submitted a bug today. It's nasty one :).

Comment: I was able to make Intellisense work in VS 15.6 by using the .ThenInclude((SaleNote)sn => sn.User) form

Comment: This still isn't working, does anyone have a link to the bug that was submitted?

Comment: Though the intellisense doesn't work out of the box due to the overload, you can do .FirstOrDefault().{whatever property} to get intellisense in a fairly painless way, then just delete the .FirstOrDefault(). It should build just fine. Alternatively you can supply the object types to ThenInclude<T, T2, T3>

Comment: Thanks @AllenRufolo for your initial comment. you saved my day. I struggled with this in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.4 Preview 4 and EF Core 3.
I should learn to not so heavily rely on Intellisense but rather on the documentation and my senses.

Comment: @Allen Refolo Thank you for your comment, closing Visual Studio and reopen it makes intellisense make sense again. Visual Studio 2019 16.3.8

Answer (score 4):

For reference, the latest release (at the time of posting) EF Core 1.1.0 also supports explicit loading for this scenario. Something like this...

```
using (var _dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    var sale = _dbContext.Sale
        .Single(s => s.Id == 1);

    _dbContext.Entry(sale)
        .Collection(n => n.SalesNotes)
        .Load();
  
    _dbContext.Entry(sale)
        .Reference(u => u.User)
        .Load();
}
```