# How to configure one to many relationship using Entity Framework Core fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am studying Entity Framework Core. I have two simple classes: `Country` and `Currency`. Currencies should have a one-to-many relationship with Countries (France, Germany, Italy etc.. all share the Euro Currency).

I want to use the fluent API only, no data annotations. The goal is to use LINQ to get the Currency Name for a Country object stored in a MYSQL database.

I defined my classes:

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryID {get; set;} // ISO3166, "US" for United States
    public string CurrencyID {get; set;} // ISO4217 "USD" for US Dollar
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual Currency Currency {get; set;}

    public Country() {};
}

public class Currency
{
    public string CurrencyID {get; set;} // ISO4217
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries {get; set;}

    public Currency(){}; 
}
```

I defined my DBSets objects in the DBContext

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries {get; set;}

public DbSet<Currency> Currencies {get; set;}
```

And I use the fluent API to define my data:

```
// Country

modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasKey(c => new { c.CountryID });
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CountryID).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CountryID).HasMaxLength(2);
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CurrencyID).IsRequired();    //Foreign Key
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CurrencyID).HasMaxLength(3); //Foreign Key

// Currency

modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasKey(c => new { c.CurrencyID });
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().Property(c => c.CurrencyID).IsRequired();  
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().Property(c => c.CurrencyID).HasMaxLength(3);
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(70);
```

Then I created some default data:

```
using (var dbContext = ContextFactory.Create(connectionString))
{
            {
    dbContext.Add(new Country(iso3166Code: "FR", name: "France", iso4217Code: "EUR"));
    dbContext.Add(new Country(iso3166Code: "DE", name: "Germany", iso4217Code: "EUR"));
    dbContext.Add(new Country(iso3166Code: "IT", name: "Italy", iso4217Code: "EUR"));
    dbContext.Add(new Country(iso3166Code: "US", name: "United States of America", iso4217Code: "USD"));
    dbContext.Add(new Currency(iso4217Code: "EUR", name: "Euro"));
    dbContext.Add(new Currency(iso4217Code: "USD", name: "US Dollar"));

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am sure the data are stored in MYSQL database and the server is running. I can connect to the database but when I try:

```
var italyCurrencyName = context.Countries.First(c => c.CountryID == "IT").Currency.Name;
WriteLine($"Italy currency is: {italyCurrencyName}");
```

I get an exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. The reason is that the Currency navigation property of the Country object appears to be null.

The following code gets the right Country object, with "EUR" set as `CurrencyID` (the foreign key) but the `Currency` property is `null`.

```
var italy = context.Countries.First(c => c.CountryID == "IT");
```

I tried to specify the relationship like this without success:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasOne(e => e.Currency).WithMany(e => e.Countries).HasForeignKey(e => e.CurrencyID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasMany(e => e.Countries);
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:

I can get my data only if I force the loading of the Currencies DbSet:

```
var italy = context.Countries.First(c => c.CountryID == "IT");
var euro = context.Currencies.First(c => c.CurrencyID == "EUR");
WriteLine($"Italy currency is: {italyCurrencyName}");
```

Comment: Did you tried Include('Currency') while select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a null value is that "lazy loading" is not yet supported by Entity Framework Core:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

To get the related data you should use "eager loading":

```
var italy = context.Countries.Include(c=>c.Currency).First(c => c.CountryID == "IT");
```

Comment: @NicolaPrada please check this link . It says that EF core has include . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044451/entity-framework-core-eager-loading-then-include-on-a-collection

Comment: @NicolaPrada you able to solve  this or still same issue?

Comment: @NicolaPrada : Can you try I updated my answer . Please change the name of the Curency it was countries before . As Currency have  navigation property of Country ,

Comment: This works: var italy = context.Countries.Include(c=>c.Currency).First(c => c.CountryID == "IT");

Comment: @NicolaPrada great to hear that . I hope you like my answer :)